# Is there such a thing as an "or" case in a dependency graph?

Tags: graphs

Suppose $A$ depends on $B$ or $C$, but not necessarily exclusively. Is it possible to model this in a dependency graph?

Can we just link $A$ to $B$ and $C$ via a diamond (like in UML) (though I don't see how this can be represented mathematically)? Or do we have to condense $B$ and $C$ to a single node $D$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to represent a general boolean function as a directed acyclic graph. Wikipedia has examples of this on the [binary decision diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) and [propositional directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_directed_acyclic_graph) pages.

In the case of the PDAG, the up triangle represents AND, the down triangle OR, and the diamond represents NOT. **The PDAG seems to be the closest to an AND/OR dependency graph**, with the topmost element only having its requirements satisfied if the function would yield a 1.

To represent this mathematically, you could use [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

[image: Propositional directed acyclic graph]