# Dependency graph with general (AND/OR) dependencies

Tags: graphs

This is similar to [Is there such a thing as an "or" case in a dependency graph?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85310/is-there-such-a-thing-as-an-or-case-in-a-dependency-graph)

I am trying to represent a dependency graph where the dependencies for an individual node may be a general boolean function of other nodes.

For example, node A may be reachable from node B or node C.

I can't see how to represent this with a DAG. Is there way to represent general boolean dependencies in a DAG? If there isn't, what other sort of structure should I use?

Comment: What is the purpose of the DAG representation?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the crappy mspaint, but you could make an intermediate layer where the nodes in the middle represent each of the combinations of (A,B), like in a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table):

[image: A or B dependency with intermediate layer]

~ABB~

Comment: all the arcs in a dependency graph have to be activated to make a node available to process. In your drawing, you have 3 in-arcs to the AorB node, and you are implicitly OR-ing all those arcs together, whereas the dependency graph requires that all 3 arcs are in place. Your AorB node, as draw, requires both A and B to be processed first.

Comment: Ok, pretend I drew all the arrows in the opposite direction. I wasn't going specifically for a dependency graph. The question more generally asked for a DAG.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to represent a general boolean function as a directed acyclic graph. Wikipedia has examples of this on the [binary decision diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) and [propositional directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_directed_acyclic_graph) pages.

In the case of the PDAG, the up triangle represents AND, the down triangle OR, and the diamond represents NOT. **The PDAG seems to be the closest to an AND/OR dependency graph**, with the topmost element only having it's requirements satisfied if the function would yield a 1.

[image: Propositional directed acyclic graph]